# html tag stops being full width on skinny viewports

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My `<html>` tag stops taking up the full width on skinny viewports (even though the applied green background-color seems to span the full width). This causes my css grid with 1 row and 1 column to become uncentred horizontally. In this screenshot I am hovering over the `<html>` tag while the viewport is skinny:

[image]

As soon as the device is wider, the `<html>` takes up the full width and the content is centred horizontally.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #46d689;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<section className="container">
        <img
          alt="logo"
          style={{
            height: "250px",
            objectFit: "contain",
          }}
          src={require("./img/logo_web.png")}
        />
        <h4 style={{ color: "#FFF" }}>The Vegan Repository</h4>
        <h4
          style={{
            color: "#FFF",
            fontWeight: "400",
            marginBottom: "0",
          }}
        >
          Find Vegan Products in your Local Community
        </h4>

        <span
          style={{
            color: "#FFF",
            marginBottom: "20px",
            display: "inline-block",
          }}
        >
          Coming Soon to iOS
        </span>
        <br />
        <div>
          {/* <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/surfboard-volcalc/id1223913734?mt=8"> */}
          <i className={"fa fa-apple fa-5x"} style={{ color: "#FFF" }}></i>
          {/* </a> */}
        </div>

        <p style={{ color: "#FFF !important" }}>
          If you have any issues, questions or suggestions, contact me directly
          at{" "}
          <span>
            <a href="mailto:bt.farquhar@gmail.com">bt.farquhar@gmail.com</a>
          </span>
        </p>
      </section>
```

Why does the `<html>` tag stop taking up full width on skinny viewports, causing my content to become uncentred?

Comment: Please, make a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
html,body{
  height: 100vh !important;
  width: 100vw !important;
}
```

It should do it.