# HTML Viewport not using full width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. On my website I refresh the data every second, but that causes fonts to resize randomly every second. To fix that I need to add the following in my html page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Only this has 1 problem for me. On my desktop, it has no effect, but when I switch to my mobile, the page width uses only like 40%, while I have the following css:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Here is an example image from the before and after:

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

The only difference is that one line. I already found this post which looks like the same problem: [html tag stops being full width on skinny viewports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466252/html-tag-stops-being-full-width-on-skinny-viewports), but that solution doesn't seem to work for me, because nothing changes when I try his solution. The table at the bottom of my page is one of the things that's getting messed up, so I will share all of the code for the table:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}

#orderHistory {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#orderHistoryContent {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#orderHistoryContent table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 14px
}

#orderHistoryContent table td, th {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}


.priceCell {
    text-align: right;
}


.order-history-header {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.order-target-price {
    visibility: visible;
}

.order-limit-price {
    visibility: visible;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {

    .order-target-price {
        display: none;
    }

    .order-limit-price {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- This line prevents jumping fonts on a mobile device -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

        <!-- CSS FILES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orderHistory.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="orderHistory">
          <label class="title">Order history</label>
          <div id="orderHistoryContent">
              <table>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Action</th>
                          <th>Market</th>
                          <th>Coin</th>
                          <th>DateTimeEntered</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Quantity</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Amount</th>
                          <th class="order-target-price">Target price</th>
                          <th class="order-limit-price">Limit price</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Price</th>
                          <th>DateTimeExecuted</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Profit</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">Buy</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(173, 204, 255);">ETH</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">2021-05-19 02:56:01</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">0.59904000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2012.27120640</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">3359.160000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2021-05-19 02:56:01</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(210, 255, 209);">Executed</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 196, 146);">Sell</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(198, 229, 173);">BTC</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">2021-05-16 15:48:33</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">0.04112200</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">2014.25425280</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">48982.400000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">2021-05-16 15:48:34</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(189, 229, 188);">Executed</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" rowspan="0" style="background-color: rgb(155, 237, 137);">
                              <b>
                                  +12.40$<br />
                                  +0.62%
                              </b>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">Buy</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(220, 255, 193);">BTC</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">2021-05-16 15:29:55</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">0.04116400</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">1999.96817068</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">48585.370000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2021-05-16 15:29:56</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(210, 255, 209);">Executed</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem in this example is that the table goes through the outer div border, while I have set the width of the outer div to 100%.
What is causing this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Which meta tag did you have before? ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">```?

Comment: I had nothing before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your div is indeed 100% of the viewport, but your table is wider than the viewport, causing the issue...

You need some `overflow` as the table elements are not super "mobile friendly" :).

Try:

```
#orderHistoryContent {
    ...
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or, if you don't like the scrolling you can instead break the content inside the table using `word-break`...

```
#orderHistoryContent table td, th { 
      word-break: break-word; 
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    width: 99%;
    margin: auto auto;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}

#orderHistory {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#orderHistoryContent {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#orderHistoryContent table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 14px
}

#orderHistoryContent table td, th {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

#orderHistoryContent.overflow { overflow: auto; }
#orderHistoryContent.word-break table td, th { word-break: break-word; }

.priceCell {
    text-align: right;
}


.order-history-header {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.order-target-price {
    visibility: visible;
}

.order-limit-price {
    visibility: visible;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {

    .order-target-price {
        display: none;
    }

    .order-limit-price {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- This line prevents jumping fonts on a mobile device -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

        <!-- CSS FILES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orderHistory.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="orderHistory">
          <label class="title">Order history (overflow)</label>
          <div id="orderHistoryContent" class="overflow">
              <table>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Action</th>
                          <th>Market</th>
                          <th>Coin</th>
                          <th>DateTimeEntered</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Quantity</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Amount</th>
                          <th class="order-target-price">Target price</th>
                          <th class="order-limit-price">Limit price</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Price</th>
                          <th>DateTimeExecuted</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Profit</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">Buy</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(173, 204, 255);">ETH</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">2021-05-19 02:56:01</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">0.59904000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2012.27120640</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">3359.160000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2021-05-19 02:56:01</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(210, 255, 209);">Executed</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 196, 146);">Sell</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(198, 229, 173);">BTC</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">2021-05-16 15:48:33</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">0.04112200</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">2014.25425280</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">48982.400000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">2021-05-16 15:48:34</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(189, 229, 188);">Executed</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" rowspan="0" style="background-color: rgb(155, 237, 137);">
                              <b>
                                  +12.40$<br />
                                  +0.62%
                              </b>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">Buy</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(220, 255, 193);">BTC</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">2021-05-16 15:29:55</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">0.04116400</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">1999.96817068</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">48585.370000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2021-05-16 15:29:56</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(210, 255, 209);">Executed</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
          <label class="title">Order history (word-break)</label>
          <div id="orderHistoryContent" class="word-break">
              <table>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Action</th>
                          <th>Market</th>
                          <th>Coin</th>
                          <th>DateTimeEntered</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Quantity</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Amount</th>
                          <th class="order-target-price">Target price</th>
                          <th class="order-limit-price">Limit price</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Price</th>
                          <th>DateTimeExecuted</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                          <th class="priceCell">Profit</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">Buy</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(173, 204, 255);">ETH</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">2021-05-19 02:56:01</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">0.59904000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2012.27120640</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">3359.160000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2021-05-19 02:56:01</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(210, 255, 209);">Executed</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 196, 146);">Sell</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(198, 229, 173);">BTC</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">2021-05-16 15:48:33</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">0.04112200</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">2014.25425280</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(229, 204, 192);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">48982.400000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(225, 229, 171);">2021-05-16 15:48:34</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(189, 229, 188);">Executed</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" rowspan="0" style="background-color: rgb(155, 237, 137);">
                              <b>
                                  +12.40$<br />
                                  +0.62%
                              </b>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;">
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">Buy</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">USDT</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(220, 255, 193);">BTC</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">2021-05-16 15:29:55</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">0.04116400</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">1999.96817068</td>
                          <td class="order-target-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="order-limit-price" style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">0.000000</td>
                          <td class="priceCell" style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">48585.370000</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">2021-05-16 15:29:56</td>
                          <td style="background-color: rgb(210, 255, 209);">Executed</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding `overflow: auto;` just cuts off the table at the border of the outer div, but the div still isn't full width, but like 40% of the screen width

Comment: It is hard to debug a code that we don't have, you just provide images... Provide your HTML, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... Basically, your tables are too wide to fit into the viewport... When you can, avoid tables

Comment: I have provided all the code to reproduce the problem. The code I gave is targeted on one single element that contains the problem. Fixing one, fixes all. Try to run my code on a mobile device or shrink your window

Comment: I can see your problem, and already tried to point you in the right direction... so, your content makes the table too wide for the viewport. Basically, your outer div is indeed 100% of the viewport, but your table is wider than the viewport... `oveflow` will keep all inside the viewport but there is a scroll... or you can try `word-break`, like: `#orderHistoryContent table td, th { word-break: break-word; }`... See the snippet, hope this help